# IE strange CSS difference compared to FF and chrome in font-size

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Please take a look at following page:

http://tarjom.ir/demo/niazer

In firefox, it is rendered all OK. But in IE, though normalize.css is used, and also compatibility properties added, still sucks. IE problem is mainly related to font-size. I have used a custom font, but its IE version is also included. Now, what causes the IE, in above link to show the sections' headers with larger fonts than FF. Here is the snapshot in IE and Firefox:
(you see the top section of the image which shows the IE rendering of the font-size, is larger than its FF counterpart. You also can see its live version from the link above)

[image]

## The problem Exists in IE8

Comment: I have checked your link in both firefox and ie and theyre both the same size. Im using ie10 and firefox 25.0.1.0. Make sure you are refreshing your css with both browsers. Your browsers may be using a cached version

Comment: I mean ie8, ie10 has many modern features...

Comment: Have you considered looking at ie8 css selectors? This would enable you to use specific css styles just for ie8.

Answer (score 1):

set for `.cats-bottom` :

```
position: relative;
```

and for `.section-title-blue`:

```
position: absolute;
right: 20%;
```

look here : http://jsfiddle.net/tseN6/

Comment: can you explain about what you have suggested? thanks

Comment: when you set relative for a div and absolute for that's child, child position is related to parent. This is standard way.

Answer (score 1):

Dear Mostafa rounded corners using css works in IE9+. if you want to have a rounded corner image you have to make the image itself round cornered.

if the background size variable you can just make round corner images and use it like this:

```
<div>
   <table border="0">
      <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>دسته های سایت</td>
      <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><img src="left-corner.png"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><img src="right-corner.png"></td>
      </tr>
   </table> 
</div>
```

Comment: I know, my problem is related to font-size, and I have quite found the problem

Comment: well if it is fon-size related give your class a fixed font-size like `font-size:16px;`